# Internet Explorer in 64 Bit Mode is not Supported in Coded UI Test Builder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I know you must gone through my error.Actually what i am facing is, when i start recording through Coded UI Test Builder it is working fine. But when i record for an item whose value is coming from server, It don't recognize the steps.Instead it gives warning that Internet Explorer in 64 Bit is not supported.

In my windows application Based Project , I have attached a File Upload Button. On its clicking event a web browser controls shows the list of some files with some controls like check Box ,Button etc. The Coded UI Builder is Only not working on that Web Browser Control.

Also Same Error is coming when i try to record something Internet Explorer(64 Bit) I am using :-

-> windows server 2008

-> Visual Studio 2010 SP 1

Please Help.

See the Error [here][1]

Answer (score 0):

CodedUI runs as a 32-bit process which is why it doesn't like the x64 version of IE. In your WinForms project please compile a version explicity for x86 and see if that solves your problem.

P.S. You can have a look at the [supported configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN to see what configurations are valid.